# Is Mundo a strong jungler?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've seen jungle Mundo a lot lately, and I usually see him lose.  I don't feel that his ganks are strong enough, and his counter jungling doesn't seem strong either.  Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 3):

Dr Mundo is a great jungler. Saintvicious from Professional team Counterlogic Gaming uses him often. He has really fast clears which allows him to counter jungle.

His ultimate and his Masochism(`E`) allows him to be really strong and really hard to take down allowing him to be very good at resisting counter jungling.

His ganks do rely on his clever so I run him with exhaust and smite to help with his ganks.

Another thing that makes him strong is that he is stronger than other junglers late game.

Comment: Thanks, I think this cleared it up.  I guess I haven't seen anyone other than saintviscous do well with him (could be saintviscous is a good player, rather than mundo), and the last jungle mundo I saw on a pro game got counter jungled pretty hard himself.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Saint ran Mundo in the Hannover tournament if you wanna check out some of those videos. not sure how well he did individually but CLG did make it through to the semi-finals (90% sure) so he couldnt have done to bad .

Comment: Haha yea.  I'll have to take a look.  Haven't seen many people play mundo until recently, maybe because of saint.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Mundo has a ***very strong*** counter jungle. With burning agony you can clear waves very fast.

He also does more damage the lower hp which helps his clear times.

His cleaver also does a lot of damage to dragon and baron.

On top of that he can absorb a lot of damage late game which can be useful during team fights.

Comment: Hadn't considered the strength for quick dragon kills.  I was concerned that his health cost on his burning agony slowed down his own jungle, or left him open for countering.

Comment: oh no, his w is shyvanas that you can turn off when you want. just think of him as shyvana, except with more ridiculous late game potential.

Answer (score 1):

Jungle mundo is just the flavor of the month jungler.  His ganks are reliant on hitting a cleaver that is not that hard to dodge with boots and his ultimate is kinda nullified with ignite.  However his counterjungling strength can make up for it in the earlier game

Answer (score 0):

People like him because he has one of the fastest clears. His ganks are actually really deadly, but it is reliant on hitting the first cleaver.